# What sets are in these mixed bags?

Tags: set-identification

I don't have the instructions nor the original box so I am unsure what set these are. Does anyone know what are the names of these Lego sets? Where to find the instructions?

1

[image]

2

[image]

3

[image]

4

[image]

5

[image]

6

[image]

7

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you have a large amount of sets from different themes and eras mixed thoroughly, which only allows the identification of a few sets that have quite distinct pieces. You could pick out the pieces for those sets and try to identify the remaining heap starting by the most unusual pieces.

For instructions I'd recommend checking Brickset. For example if you need the documents for [3847: Magma Monster](https://brickset.com/sets/3847-1/Magma-Monster), you'd look up that set and find [the instructions below the main image](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/4603710.pdf).

---

Now, for your photos:

The balloon tires in the first image are called [Tire 81.6 x 38 R Balloon](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=45982&in=S), available in 16 sets. The thinner tire is called [Tire 94.2mm D. x 22mm Motorcycle Racing Tread](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=88516&in=S), available in 8 sets. The [Orange Dish 8 x 8](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3961&colorID=4&in=A), as identified by Phil B., appeared in 3 SpongeBob sets from 2006 and a city set from 2010, besides an obscure FIRST LEGO League set.

The baseplate in image #2 is [Baseplate, Raised 32 x 48 x 6 with Level Front](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=51542&in=S), contained in 3 sets in gray and two in tan (presumably the one under it has the same pattern).

The wings in the third image are [Wing Plate 20 x 56 with 6 x 10 Cutout and No Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54093&idColor=85#T=C&C=85) in dark bluish gray, these are definitely from [7683 - Fight on the Flying Wing](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7683-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

The orange baseplate in image #5 is [Orange Baseplate 16 x 16](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3867&colorID=4&in=A), from [3847 - Magma Monster](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3847-1).

Images #4, #5,  #6 and #7 depict seemingly unopened bags, which would mean their contents belong to a single set.

The top bag of #6 has *Technic Engine Cylinder with Side Slots (2850a)*, *Technic, Liftarm, Modified Bent Thick 1 x 11.5 Double (32009)* and *Technic, Gear 40 Tooth (3649)*, which together with the red fairing have only appeared in [8051 Motorbike](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8051-1).

Bag #1 here seems to be from [8088: ARC-170 Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8088-1), as the *Dark Green Brick, Round 2 x 2 Dome Top with Pearl Dark Gray Pattern (R4-P44)* only appears in that single set.

Image #6 bag #2 has both [Dark Tan Wheel 31mm D. x 15mm Technic](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=60208&colorID=69&in=A) and a *Light Bluish Gray Technic, Brick 1 x 14 with Holes*, together only ever released in [8096: Emperor Palpatine's Shuttle](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8096-1).

Bag #3 of Image #6 seems to be from [7930: Bounty Hunter Assault Gunship](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=7930-1) based on the *Dark Bluish Gray Technic, Axle 8L with Stop*, *Dark Bluish Gray Plate, Round 4 x 4 with Hole*, *Dark Bluish Gray Wheel 31mm D. x 15mm Technic*, *Yellow Cylinder 4 x 4 x 1 2/3 with Pin Holes and Center Bar* and *Dark Green Cylinder Half 2 x 4 x 5 with 1 x 2 Cutout*.

On the bottom left, bag #4 has a *Light Bluish Gray Technic, Axle Connector Hub with 3 Axles*, a *White Plate 4 x 6* and most importantly one *White Tile 2 x 2 with Groove with Ninjago Cracked Red Skull on Black Circle Pattern*, which only appear together in [2506: Skull Truck](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=2506-1).

The packages in image #7 are way too hard to identify, since they are not laid out neatly as in #6, so partially overlap each other and the loose parts underneath them, so please upload a separate image in the style of #6 if your own efforts remain unsuccessful.

Comment: That 3961 Dish 8x8 in Orange is in 5 sets, including 3 from the Spongebob series.